# Cannot access the nested formGroup's value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

I am creating nested formGroup fields. The following is my html

```html
<form [formGroup]="userProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="bookUser()" class="form">
    <!-- userName -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" formControlName="userName">
    </div>

    <!-- mobile -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mobileNumber">Mobile:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" formControlName="mobileNumber">
    </div>

    <!-- emailId -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailId">Email id:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailId" formControlName="emailId">
    </div>

    <!-- password -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" formControlName="password">
    </div>

    <!-- address -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div formGroupName="address">
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" formControlname="city">

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" formControlname="state">

        <label for="zipCode">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" formControlname="zipCode">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</button>
</form>
```

And below is the typescript i am using...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userProfileForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      userName:['', Validators.required],
      mobileNumber:['', Validators.required],
      emailId:['', Validators.required],
      password:['', Validators.required],
      address: this.formBuilder.group({
        city:['', Validators.required],
        state:['', Validators.required],
        zipCode:['', Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
```

I do not receive the `city` formControl of the child formGroup when i try to print it in the html.
I tried accessing the value in different ways like:
`(<FormGroup>this.userProfileForm.get('address')).get('city').value;`
and
`this.city=this.userProfileForm['controls'].address['controls'].city.value`
but i still can't get the city field to display in html.
I also used `this.city=this.userProfileForm['controls'].address['controls'].city.valid` and it always returns false.

I have also created 2 model classes:
UserProfile

```
import { Address } from "./address";

export class UserProfile{
    userName:string;
    emailId:string;
    password:string;
    mobileNumber:string;
    address:Address;
}
```

Address

```
export class Address{
    city:string;
    state:string;
    zipCode:string;
}
```

How do i access the nested formGroup values?? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine. Its a typing error your wrote `formControlname` instead of `formControlName`. Change small n to Capital N.

```
<div formGroupName="address">
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" formControlName="city">

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" formControlName="state">

        <label for="zipCode">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" formControlName="zipCode">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please find the following solution of @Somdatt_Bhadvariya on [How to
>   use formControlName and deal with nested formGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499425/how-to-use-formcontrolname-and-deal-with-nested-formgroup) it worked for
>   me.

**Typescript:**

```
 this.myForm = fb.group({
        'fullname': ['', Validators.required],
        'gender': [],
        'address': fb.group({
            'street': [''],
            'houseNumber': [''],
            'postalCode': ['']
        })
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" >
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fullname">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="fullname" class="form-control">            
       </div>
       <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <label>
          <input type="radio" formControlName="gender" [value]="gender">{{ gender }} </label>
       </div>
       <div formGroupName="address">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="street">Username</label>
             <input type="text" id="username" value="street" formControlName="street" class="form-control">            
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="houseNumber">Username</label>
             <input type="text" id="username" value="street" formControlName="houseNumber" class="form-control">            
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="postalCode">Username</label>
             <input type="text" id="username" value="street" formControlName="postalCode" class="form-control">            
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```