# angular reactive forms form group as formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form group inside the group i have another form group how can i add formControlName to inputs inside profile form group? fo example
`<input formControlName="profile.company_name">` but it doesn't work

```
      userForm = new FormGroup({
    isActive: new FormControl(false),
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    login: new FormControl(),
    userType: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    emailAddress: new FormControl(),
    reference: new FormControl(),
    entity: new FormControl(),
    type: new FormControl(''),
    profile: new FormGroup({
      company_name: new FormControl(),
      address: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      zipCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      phoneMobile: new FormControl(),
      defaultEntity: new FormControl(),
      phone: new FormControl(),
      gender: new FormControl(),
    })
  });
```

Comment: Refer this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499425/how-to-use-formcontrolname-and-deal-with-nested-formgroup

Comment: You should use `<div formGroupName="profile">..here your inputs</div>`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ng-container formGroupName="profile"> <input formControlName="company_name" class="form-control"> </ng-container>`