# Cannot find control with name:

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a quite complicated form which I want to break down into individual components. Here is my base form (only taken example fields), I'm using `FormBuilder`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.predictorQuestion = this.fb.group({
  question: ['', Validators.required],
  options: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
  ]),
  meta_options: this.fb.group({
   test_type: ['', Validators.required],
  })
});

get meta_options() {
  return this.predictorQuestion.get('meta_options') as FormGroup;
}

get options() {
  return this.predictorQuestion.get('options') as FormArray;
}
```

If I try to connect this to my templates, it works perfectly:

```
<form [formGroup]="predictorQuestion" fxLayout="column">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="question">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <button (click)="addOption()" matTooltip="Add option" matTooltipPosition="right" mat-mini-fab type="button">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div formArrayName="options" fxLayout="column">
    <div *ngFor="let answer of options.controls; let i = index" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Option {{ i+1 }} </mat-label>
        <input fxFlex matInput [formControlName]="i">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Remove this option" matTooltipPosition="right" (click)="removeOption(i)">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div formGroupName="meta_options" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
      <mat-select formControlName="test_type">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let vtype of vtypes" value="{{ vtype.value }}">{{ vtype.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

This renders without any errors.

If I try to break down the `meta_options.test_type` in a component of its own in a way like:

`component.ts`

```
@Input() parent_form: FormGroup;
public vtypes: Array<Object>;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.vtypes = [
      {
        name: 'Timestamp',
        value: 'timestamp'
      },
      {
        name: 'Over',
        value: 'over'
      }
    ];
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="25" [formGroup]="parent_form">
  <mat-select formControlName="test_type">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let vtype of vtypes" value="{{ vtype.value }}">{{ vtype.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and using this component in my main parent form as

```
<meta-option-value [parent_form]="predictorQuestion"></meta-option-value>
```

**I get the following error:**

```
"Cannot find the control with the name: 'test_type'"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find control with name: formControlName in angular 2 or 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431613/cannot-find-control-with-name-formcontrolname-in-angular-2-or-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the complete `FormGroup (predictorQuestion)` to the child. You only need to pass the `predictorQuestion.get('meta_types')` to the `parent_form` as `[parent_form]="predictorQuestion.get('meta_types')"`.

Answer (score 1):

pass the "control" itseft and use [FormControl] in your children

```
<meta-option-value [formControl]="predictorQuestion.get('meta_options')">
</meta-option-value>
```

Your meta-options

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="25" [formControl]="formControl">
  ...

</mat-form-field>

//and add the Input
@Input()formControl: FormControl;
```

the same idea work if you need to pass a FormGroup or a Form Array

Answer (score 0):

You can say your child component to use `formControlName="test_type"` depending on parent container regardless container's type(FormGroupName, FormGroup orr FormArray) by defining `viewProviders`:

**meta-option-value.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'meta-option-value',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
      <mat-select formControlName="test_type">
        <mat-option ...>{{ vtype.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
  viewProviders: [{
    provide: ControlContainer,
    useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
    deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
  }]
})
export class MetaOptionValueComponent {
  ...
}
```

**parent.template.html**

```typescript
<div formGroupName="meta_options">
                     /\
                     ||
              will look at this group   
    <meta-option-value></meta-option-value>
</div>
```

As you can see MetaOptionValueComponent contains only its own related logic.

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv9nvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

See also:

- [Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/46748943#46748943)

Of course, another way is passing FormGroup or FormControl instance and use it directly as suggested in other answers